# MPMoviePlayerViewController modal quits unexpectedly

Tags: iphone, media-player

I am currently trying to play a movie (MP4) using base sdk 3.2 for ipad. I managed to get the movieplayer to pop up but it closes down straight away. I tried changing the file format to read an MP4 link

http://www.yo-yo.org/mp4/yu3.mp4

Below is the test code:(Not taking care of mem release etc..yet)

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:remote_videoUrl];
            MPMoviePlayerViewController* theMoviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
            theMoviePlayer.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
            [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:theMoviePlayer];
```

Anyone got any idea. Someone said if the file format is wrong then it will close but shouldn't an MP4 video play ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Had an error in my url :) stupid me.